# Osmosis no space left on device

Tags: osmosis

Issue with performing extracts on compressed file results in error
`Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device`

Background:
I am working on extracting city data from a europe-latest.osm.pbf compressed file. The compressed file is ~24.6gb and my 500gb ssd has ~280gb left in space.

Does osmosis work by decompressing the entire file and then performing the processing steps on the uncompressed file? I have tried working with a extract of italy-latest.osm.pbf for example as well as the italy-latest.osm uncompressed and we get the same general error in the --rbf and --rb flag options.

I don't know if I'm expecting too much from my computer or I am missing some Java variables that are artificially limiting my ability to perform the extracts. I don't have any experience with Java so might be missing something simple.

Example:

```
osmosis --rb europe-latest.osm.pbf --bounding-polygon file="polygons/milan.poly" completeRelations=yes --write-xml milan-relations.osm
```

which fails at

```
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rb failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to write long 1038967750 to the store.
```

Comment: You'll need a bigger disk